# See what application uses the webcam Data

Tags: webcam

I have a c270 Logitech webcam and I just noticed, that the LED is on, indicating that the webcam is recording. However there is no application (I would be aware of) using the webcam. So how do I find out how and what activated it?

System is ubuntu 12.04 with the 3.4 rc 4 kernel

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use lsof to track back what is accessing a file.  I, personally, have a homebrew app that uses lsof and an underlying API to let me know when something opens my webcam.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. However lsof /dev/video0 does not return anything as normal user and returns "lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfs-fuse-daemon file system /home/clemens/.gvfs
      Output information may be incomplete." when run as root

Comment: I also checked the usb data in wireshark, but there was no visible data transfer from the camera. Still very strange that the LED is on.

Comment: when I open the webcam in skype it shows up in wireshark as well as in lsof. So this could just have been a glitch in the driver/module. Still gave me quite a shock.

Comment: Strange... lsof /dev/video0 has this output.
WARNING: can't stat() aufs file system /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/xxxx